# Ошибка <Response [200]> python vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, http, requests

Пишу программу на python для выкладывания постов с изображением в группу Vk. Использую библиотеку vk_api и requests.
Собственно вот сама программа:

```
import vk_api
import time
import random
import datetime
import requests



token='токен пользователя (доступ к wall и photos)'
group_id=id групы
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
gWUS=vk.method('photos.getWallUploadServer',{'group_id':group_id})
album_id=gWUS['album_id']
user_id=gWUS['user_id']
upload_url=gWUS['upload_url']
file={'photo1':open('q.png','rb')}
ur=requests.post(upload_url,files=file)
print(ur)
```

При запуске выводит

> Response [200]

.
Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо! Как отметить что вопрос решён, и пометить комментарий?

Comment: Я переделал комментарий в ответ. Рядом с ответом слева есть галка, ее нужно поставить, если считаете, что ответ вам помог. Вопрос как-то специально помечать как решенный не нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не ошибка, это успешный результат (см. [Список кодов состояния HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP)). Чтобы получить текст ответа, нужно брать поле `text`, например:

```
print(ur.text)
```